# Python creating a variable to store object information automatically

Tags: python, oop, variables

Maybe I am looking at the problem wrong.

However, here's what I am up against.  I decided to try and learn some OOP today and decided to focus on creating a deck of cards and games to draw and players etc.

So I'm at the point right now where I want to write def playerJoins(deckToDrawFrom, startingHandSize, name).

Now, how would I create the Player() without actually typing say player6 = Player(gameDeck, 7, 'Bertha')

how could I do something like player(n) = Player(. . . . . .) so that every time the function was called, it made a new instance of the Player() but under a new 'n' number (that way I can draw them some cards from the deck and keep track of the deck size that way.)

Am I looking at this wrong?  It's my first day, please help. HAHA

Comment: Use a list of players, instead of having names for each player object. `players.append(Player(gameDeck, 7, 'Bertha'))`

Comment: Oh okay, yeah that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you instantiate a new `Player`, append it to a list or add it to a dict. Also can't help buy say this, in python it is convention to use `name_with_underscores` (forgotten the name of the case) for variable/field names.

Comment: Oh okay, instead of gameDeck it's game_deck instead then?

Comment: yeah, it's not exactly a massive issue, it won't affect the running of your code, just thought I'd mention it as that's python convention.

Comment: Okay, I'll be changing that on the next project then.  Probably going to go read up on what's pythonic.  I appreciate the feedback.